# How to implement a weighted product of likelihoods for multiple random variables in pyMC3?

Tags: bayesian, pymc3

I need to build a super-likelihood function from several random variables. The distribution of each variable is standard.

Using two random variables as an example, the target super-likelihood is like this: 
S = F1^w1 * F2^w2 (s.t. w1 + w2 = 1)
or equivalently, 
logS = w1 logF1 + w2 log F1 (s.t. w1 + w2 = 1).

Where F1 ~ Normal distribution and F2 ~ Bernoulli distribution

I use the following codes

```
data = <load my data> 

[w1,w2] = [0.5,0.5]

with Model() as model:
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu',lower=0,upper=1)
    sd = pm.Uniform('sd',lower=0,upper=1)
    p = pm.Uniform('p',lower=0,upper=1)

    F1 = pm.Normal("F1", mu = mu, sigma = sd)
    F1 = pm.Bernoulli("F2",p)

    S = pm.Deterministic('S',F1**w1*F2**w2, observed=data)

    step = Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(2000, step=step)
```

But it does not work.

Please help to implement such a weighted likelihood model in pyMC3.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this thread: [What is pm.Potential in PyMC3?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251280/what-is-pm-potential-in-pymc3) `Deterministic` does not support an `observed` argument; instead, one evaluates the likelihood of the observations and adds it to the total likelihood through `pm.Potential`. Or `pm.DensityDist` is another way of doing it (e.g., [this thread](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/model-with-extended-likelihood-function-using-pm-densitydist-or-pm-potential/1634)).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for the Mixture function: https://docs.pymc.io/api/distributions/mixture.html#pymc3.distributions.mixture.Mixture

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Do you know how to implement this mixture model: a bernoulli + a Gaussian?